# Property of $f:R^n \to R$ that is continuously differentiable

Tags: calculus, inequality

Given a function $f: \mathbf{R}^n \to \mathbf{R}$ that is continuously differentiable, Show that given $v \in \mathbf{R}^n$ with $\|v\|=1$, the following inequality holds: 
$$
\left|\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}(x)\right|\le\Vert\nabla f(x)\Vert
$$
I tried to write $v=(v_1,...,v_n), D_f(x) = (x_1,...,x_n)$ and use the fact that 
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}v}  (x) = D_f(x)*v
$$ 
and then the inequality becomes equivalent to: 
$$|x_1v_1+...+x_nv_n| \leq \sqrt{x_1^2+...+x_n^2}$$ where $v_1^2+...+v_n^2=1$, and I don't know how to continue. Is this the way to go or is there a better approach? Thanks

Comment: [Cauchy–Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy–Schwarz_inequality) ...

Comment: @MartinR yes I just realized that myself! How dumb, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality:
$$
\left|\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}(x)\right| = | \langle \nabla f(x), v \rangle | \le \Vert \nabla f(x) \Vert_2 \cdot \Vert v \Vert_2 =  \Vert \nabla f(x) \Vert_2  \, .
$$